You won't believe what John's hostesses discovered
This is a three-dimensional crossword. The seven grids below depict the layers of a 7x7x7 cube. "Across" and "down" clues work like in normal crosswords, and "away" clues go through the layers, using circled cells only.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. John's hostesses discovered he's frequently almost fully nude (4)
4. Unfinished book describing everyday activities (3)
6. She met 5 down January 6th in Congress (4)
8. Eggs and avocado brought over (3)
10. Scratch middle of dark stone? (4)
12. Beyond the far edge of system, radiation reveals an orbiter (3)
13. Native American people had system of religious beliefs (5)
14. Type of exploit to lose mass (3)
15. Schedule a computer network to be backed up (4)
17. Apple consumer guide very limited (3)
19. College to dons: "Evacuation after evacuation!" (4)
21. Did Yank cut off someone like Prof. McGonagall giving talk? (3, abbr.)
22. "Use steroids, fool!" – that's fantastic insider knowledge (4)
23. One flaps its wings at night after turning around to give space (3)
25. The P in RIP (not English!) (4)
28. Jafe and Mr Gates bribe gutless representative (6)
29. The man's taken off suit – the dark ones are evil magic (4)
31. Massive beast heads to evil lair and kills (3)
32. Present Q qua Q's superior? (3)
36. Aladdin's #1 short bud (3)
38. Small present is a welcome sight on Christmas? (4)
39. Cursed, troubled djinn briefly caught ten men after disrobing (6)
40. Make changes to Morse's single period, in two different ways (4)
41. Kim's ready to be accomplished (3)
42. Dashed lines pedestrian makes use of (4)
45. For each one, dumping love? That might be Tinder (3)
48/49. Group often seen wearing leather and spikes just as Pride unfolds (5,6)
50/54. Brazil? It's hardly primarily associated with metal album (7,5)
52. Be better packers than the Green Bay Packers? (6)
54. (See 50 across)
55. It marks the ending of females! (3)
56. Musical record is suppressed by the District (4)
58. Hastily placate learner departing quickly (2,4)
63. Too fashionable to go after tip from Armani (2,4)
64. Spooner's thug, a web forum authority, is a supernatural power at night (4,3)
65. Best to leave you for a down-and-out drifter (5)
67. Attention: Trainee fails to stop one jamming in the office? (7)
69. Press 62 down after ½, @, Shift, Esc, Insert, C, Enter (6)
70. Run away from Mercedes assembly, not fully presented (6)
72. Vessel filled with horror making rounds (6)
75. American court passed piece of legislation (3)
77. Setter's not seen in red vehicle (3)
79. Workers once again wearing cow hide (4)
80. Cole's struggling to quarter military police forces (7)
81. Fats Domino's violinist plays ascending seconds (4)
82. I'm not sure what to say to capture the essence of Milan, a city famous for its grandiose church (3)
83. One shilling – major denomination (3)
84. University's very long applications (6)
85. Song about special home made drug (7)
91. My two cents: The first, and second (3, abbr.)
92. Johnny Law is imprisoning John D. Soggy? (7)
95. Gravel dispersed to encircle a holiday destination (7)
97. We objectified her after undressing – that is exploitation (3)
98. Picks out TVs (7)
99. A woman's last name? No, her first (3)
101. Performance finally shown in explosive big 16 down? (4)
104. Nazis surrendering hospital in Polanski film (4)
106. Getting into the new year gala at last is a sucker's object? (4)
107. Brown Tiger, say, losing tail (3)
108. Eat bananas – is that the English breakfast? (3)
109. Born in endless poverty (3)
110. Second amendment's conclusion: Elderly neighbour faces automatic weapon (4, abbr.)
111. Part of film aurally and visually perceived (4)
112. Writer must relinquish diamonds; that's a precondition for deal (4)
113. British flyers, or Danish ones? (3, abbr.)
Down
2. Brown, maybe black belt? (3)
3. Like some parking spaces around Perth – regularly just close to packed (7)
4. Doctor Moore, an Italian suicide victim (5)
5. I was repelled by right-wing extremist scumbag – looking back, he behaved like an ape (6)
6. Lead of Unleashed, Jet Li, playing dramatic character (6)
11. Annoyed participants in 0-0 game ultimately covered in papers (5)
16. Remove the uppermost part and cover with a new layer (3)
23. Amphibian forcibly moved in the amphitheatre (4)
24. Preliminary guess at when the destination will be reached: Shortly after eleven (4)
26. Union leader is almost victim of fratricide (3)
27. Ma's instrument, for couple of dollars, acquired by corporate exec (5)
30. Angry mob, in the 62 down, breaks into violent attack (5)
34. Narrated novel is appreciated (4)
35. Double weight in metal container (4)
37. Participants in community college (3)
42. Server's opening pop up tool (3)
43. Repeats lines for roles, including 4 down, to receive Oscar (7)
44. Performed together for total disappointment, needing to incorporate better content (7)
46. Quiet siesta is disturbed – who can be blamed? (7)
47. That's completely ridiculous! Oh and by the way, be quiet! (4)
50. Bad singer on the radio (4)
53. Not being allowed to finish, Costa Rican becomes a jerk (3)
57. Woman honoured with prestigious title and medal surprisingly left out (4)
59. A couple is excessively loud (3)
60. Writer with broken cane showing remorse (7)
61. Familiar sound on an old-timey street: Lawman apprehending outlaws, essentially (4)
62. Objective conclusion: Death is close (3)
65. It can get you around the city and last in permanent memory (4)
66. Body decapitated roughly (2,2)
67. Type of chart made out of two numbers, both approximately three (3)
68. 16 down provider of support when driving (3)
71. Chinese City's rivals surround the heart of Nanchang (6)
72. Gives a lesson to swimming groups (7)
73. Old West gunslinger, clumsy loser that's a lone protector of a canal (7)
74. Like a jungle in Wales – wild, in the middle of unoccupied lands (7)
78. Go on, you may need it to get into position in the States (6)
85. Wine spilt in Hitchcock comedy (3)
86. Single bread in Lima with hint of olive (4)
87. Hermit is old, near dead (7)
88. Supplements for Tour de France participants? (6)
89. Growth done wrong (4)
90. Shady fellow's red dog out of control (6)
93. European letters sent back by a North American country (4)
94. Square in Rome presented before a new emperor (4)
96. Journalist closer to Charles Edwards? (3)
99. One feels pain; it means periodically cutting beauty sleep a little short (7)
100. Have to enter home that's the most elegant (7)
102. Many a tract of land in Quebec is extremely ancient and endless (7)
103. People renting a very small army? (7)
104. Every second, the insects will show principle (5)
105. Cannibalised, with or without skin (5)
Away
7. Australian runner married in Brussels (3)
9. Have a lamb cut – it's baby meat! (4)
13. For instance, the Pink Panther's automobile, overly narrow at the front (7)
18. The signs of life of Ukrainian possibly revolved around it (6)
19. Start and finish (7)
20. Ukrainian seasoned criminal given one tablet instead of two (7)
28. Mary and her subject perhaps overlooked railway symbol (6)
33. Engineer slept with a chief (6)
51. Divide place and grab a chair on both sides of it (5)
76. Yours truly refused to get involved with unaugmented carrier (3)

I hate the click-bait style of the title.

Haha, I love it - great parody :)

@FlorianF Fine, I can change it to "100+ INSANE clues only people with GENIUS IQ can solve"

Lol.  OK, maybe I am a bit oversensitive.

Ah, nice 3d puzzle!

Very nice! Grid

 

With thanks to user39583 for some things that I'd missed
Across

 1. John's hostesses discovered he's frequently almost fully nude (4) ADAM = (M)ADAM(S)


 4. Unfinished book describing everyday activities (3) RUT = RUT(-H)


 6. She met 5 down January 6th in Congress (4) JANE = JAN + 6th letter of Congress


 8. Eggs and avocado brought over (3) OVA = AVO<


 10. Scratch middle of dark stone? (4) UNIT = UN(-L)IT


 12. Beyond the far edge of system, radiation reveals an orbiter (3) MIR = M + IR


 13. Native American people had system of religious beliefs (5) CREED = CREE'D


 14. Type of exploit to lose mass (3) ILK = (-M)ILK


 15. Schedule a computer network to be backed up (4) ROTA = (A TOR)<


 17. Apple consumer guide very limited (3) EVE = _E VE_


 19. College to dons: "Evacuation after evacuation!" (4) ETON = E_N  around TO


 21. Did Yank cut off someone like Prof. McGonagall giving talk? (3, abbr.) TED = T(-WITCH)ED


 22. "Use steroids, fool!" – that's fantastic insider knowledge (4) DOPE 4def


 23. One flaps its wings at night after turning around to give space (3) TAB = BAT<


 25. The P in RIP (not English!) (4) PACE = P(-E)ACE &lit


 28. Jafe and Mr Gates bribe gutless representative (6) MEMBER = ME + M(B_E)R


 29. The man's taken off suit – the dark ones are evil magic (4) ARTS =(-HE)ARTS


 31. Massive beast heads to evil lair and kills (3) ELK = E_ + L_ + K_


 32. Present Q qua Q's superior? (3) ASK = AS + K (King superior to Queen)


 36. Aladdin's #1 short bud (3) ABU = A_ + BU_ &lit


 38. Small present is a welcome sight on Christmas? (4) SNOW = S + NOW


 39. Cursed, troubled djinn briefly caught ten men after disrobing (6) JINXED = X+ _E_ in (DJIN_)*


 40. Make changes to Morse's single period, in two different ways (4) EDIT = E + DIT


 41. Kim's ready to be accomplished (3) WON ddef


 42. Dashed lines pedestrian makes use of (4) SPED = _S PED_


 45. For each one, dumping love? That might be Tinder (3) APP = A P(-O)P


 48/49. Group often seen wearing leather and spikes just as Pride unfolds (5,6) JUDAS PRIEST = (JUST AS PRIDE)*


 50/54. Brazil? It's hardly primarily associated with metal album (7,5) BRITISH = BR + IT IS + H + STEEL


 52. Be better packers than the Green Bay Packers? (6) OUTFIT ddef


 54. (See 50 across)


 55. It marks the ending of females! (3) ESS ('s') = -ESS (suffix) ddef &lit


 56. Musical record is suppressed by the District (4) DISC = D(IS)C


 58. Hastily placate learner departing quickly (2,4) AT PACE = (P(-L)ACATE)*


 63. Too fashionable to go after tip from Armani (2,4) AS WELL = A_ + SWELL


 64. Spooner's thug, a web forum authority, is a supernatural power at night (4,3) MOON GOD = "GOON MOD"


 65. Best to leave you for a down-and-out drifter (5) TRAMP = TR(U/A)MP


 67. Attention: Trainee fails to stop one jamming in the office? (7) PRINTER = PR + INTER(-N)


 69. Press 62 down after ½, @, Shift, Esc, Insert, C, Enter (6) ACCESS = A(-T) + (ESC)* around C + _S


 70. Run away from Mercedes assembly, not fully presented (6) EMCEED = (ME(-R)CEDE(-S))*


 72. Vessel filled with horror making rounds (6) SHELLS = S(HELL)S


 75. American court passed piece of legislation (3) ACT = A + CT


 77. Setter's not seen in red vehicle (3) CAR = CAR(-MINE)


 79. Workers once again wearing cow hide (4) CREW = RE- in C_W


 80. Cole's struggling to quarter military police forces (7) COMPELS = (COLES)* around MP


 81. Fats Domino's violinist plays ascending seconds (4) OILS = Second letters of Domino's ... ascending


 82. I'm not sure what to say to capture the essence of Milan, a city famous for its grandiose church (3) ULM = U(_L_)M


 83. One shilling – major denomination (3) ISM = I + S + M


 84. University's very long applications (6) USAGES = U'S AGES


 85. Song about special home made drug (7) ASPIRIN = A(SP)IR + IN


 91. My two cents: The first, and second (3, abbr.) IMO = I + MO


 92. Johnny Law is imprisoning John D. Soggy? (7) FLOODED = F(LOO + D)ED


 95. Gravel dispersed to encircle a holiday destination (7) ALGARVE = GRAVEL* around A


 97. We objectified her after undressing – that is exploitation (3) USE = US + _E


 98. Picks out TVs (7) SCREENS ddef


 99. A woman's last name? No, her first (3) ANN = A + _N + N


 101. Performance finally shown in explosive big 16 down? (4) TENT = T(_E)NT


 104. Nazis surrendering hospital in Polanski film (4) TESS = T(-H)E SS


 106. Getting into the new year gala at last is a sucker's object? (4) TEAT = TE(_A)T


 107. Brown Tiger, say, losing tail (3) TAN = TAN(-K)


 108. Eat bananas – is that the English breakfast? (3) TEA = EAT*


 109. Born in endless poverty (3) NEE = NEE(-D)


 110. Second amendment's conclusion: Elderly neighbour faces automatic weapon (4, abbr.) STEN = S + _T + E_ + N_


 111. Part of film aurally and visually perceived (4) SEEN = "SCENE"


 112. Writer must relinquish diamonds; that's a precondition for deal (4) ANTE =(-D)ANTE


 113. British flyers, or Danish ones? (3, abbr.) SAS ddef

Down

 2. Brown, maybe black belt? (3) DAN ddef


 3. Like some parking spaces around Perth – regularly just close to packed (7) METERED = M(ET)ERE + _D


 4. Doctor Moore, an Italian suicide victim (5) ROMEO = MOORE*


 5. I was repelled by right-wing extremist scumbag – looking back, he behaved like an ape (6) TARZAN = (NAZ(-I) RAT)<


 6. Lead of Unleashed, Jet Li, playing dramatic character (6) JULIET = (U_ JET LI)*


 11. Annoyed participants in 0-0 game ultimately covered in papers (5) IRKED = I(R+K+_E)D


 16. Remove the uppermost part and cover with a new layer (3) TOP ddef


 23. Amphibian forcibly moved in the amphitheatre (4) TOAD = "TOWED"


 24. Preliminary guess at when the destination will be reached: Shortly after eleven (4) BETA = B + ETA


 26. Union leader is almost victim of fratricide (3) ABE = ABE(-L)


 27. Ma's instrument, for couple of dollars, acquired by corporate exec (5) CELLO = CE(LL)O


 30. Angry mob, in the 62 down, breaks into violent attack (5) RABID = RA(_B)ID


 34. Narrated novel is appreciated (4) KNEW = "NEW"


 35. Double weight in metal container (4) TWIN = T(W)IN


 37. Participants in community college (3) UNI = _UNI_


 42. Server's opening pop up tool (3) SAP = S_ + PA<


 43. Repeats lines for roles, including 4 down, to receive Oscar (7) PARROTS = PAR(R+O)TS


 44. Performed together for total disappointment, needing to incorporate better content (7) DUETTED =DU(_ETTE_)D


 46. Quiet siesta is disturbed – who can be blamed? (7) PATSIES = P + SIESTA*


 47. That's completely ridiculous! Oh and by the way, be quiet! (4) PSSH = PS + SH


 50. Bad singer on the radio (4) BASE = "BASS"


 53. Not being allowed to finish, Costa Rican becomes a jerk (3) TIC = TIC(-O)


 57. Woman honoured with prestigious title and medal surprisingly left out (4) DAME = MEDA(-L)*


 59. A couple is excessively loud (3) TWO = "TOO"


 60. Writer with broken cane showing remorse (7) PENANCE = PEN + CANE*


 61. Familiar sound on an old-timey street: Lawman apprehending outlaws, essentially (4) CLOP = C(_L_)OP


 62. Objective conclusion: Death is close (3) END 4def


 65. It can get you around the city and last in permanent memory (4) TRAM = _T + RAM


 66. Body decapitated roughly (2,2) OR SO =(-T)ORSO


 67. Type of chart made out of two numbers, both approximately three (3) PIE = PI + E


 68. 16 down provider of support when driving (3) TEE ddef


 71. Chinese City's rivals surround the heart of Nanchang (6) MANCHU = MAN(_CH_) U


 72. Gives a lesson to swimming groups (7) SCHOOLS ddef


 73. Old West gunslinger, clumsy loser that's a lone protector of a canal (7) EARPLUG = EARP + LUG


 74. Like a jungle in Wales – wild, in the middle of unoccupied lands (7) LAWLESS = L_S around WALES*


 78. Go on, you may need it to get into position in the States (6) RESUME ddef


 85. Wine spilt in Hitchcock comedy (3) ALF = ALF(-RED)


 86. Single bread in Lima with hint of olive (4) SOLO = SOL + O_


 87. Hermit is old, near dead (7) ISOLATE = IS + O + LATE


 88. Supplements for Tour de France participants? (6) RIDERS ddef


 89. Growth done wrong (4) NODE = DONE*


 90. Shady fellow's red dog out of control (6) DODGER = (RED DOG)*


 93. European letters sent back by a North American country (4) TAUS = _T + A US


 94. Square in Rome presented before a new emperor (4) IVAN = IV (4 in Rome) + A + N


 96. Journalist closer to Charles Edwards? (3) EDS = ED + _S


 99. One feels pain; it means periodically cutting beauty sleep a little short (7) ANTENNA = even letters of PAIN IN MEANS + NA(-P)


 100. Have to enter home that's the most elegant (7) NEATEST = N(EAT)EST


 102. Many a tract of land in Quebec is extremely ancient and endless (7) ESTATES = EST + A_T + E_S


 103. People renting a very small army? (7) TENANTS = TEN ANTS


 104. Every second, the insects will show principle (5) TENET = odd letters of THE INSECTS


 105. Cannibalised, with or without skin (5) EATEN = (-E)ATE(-N)

Away

 7. Australian runner married in Brussels (3) EMU = E(M)U


 9. Have a lamb cut – it's baby meat! (4) VEAL = _VE A L_


 13. For instance, the Pink Panther's automobile, overly narrow at the front (7) CARTOON = CAR + TOO + N_


 18. The signs of life of Ukrainian possibly revolved around it (6) VITALS = IT inside SLAV<


 19. Start and finish (7) EXECUTE ddef


 20. Ukrainian seasoned criminal given one tablet instead of two (7) ODESSAN = (SEASONED-E)*


 28. Mary and her subject perhaps overlooked railway symbol (6) MASCOT = MA(-RY) + SCOT


 33. Engineer slept with a chief (6) STAPLE = (SLEPT A)*


 51. Divide place and grab a chair on both sides of it (5) SPLIT = S(PL)IT


 76. Yours truly refused to get involved with unaugmented carrier (3) ASS = AS (-I)S

user39583 notes that there is structure to some of the solutions layers, specifically:

 The pairs ROMEO and JULIET; TARZAN and JANE in the first grid. The band and album JUDAS PRIEST and BRITISH STEEL in the third grid. The seventh grid only using the letters AENST.


@user39583 Thanks for those! Now added.
